# How to implement proxy agent using SMNP4J

Tags: java, proxy, snmp, snmp4j

I am coding proxy agent (SNMP v2c) using the SNMP4J library.

I started with the code from [here](http://s16675406.onlinehome-server.info/pipermail/snmp4j/2007-March/001976.html).

The proxy agent (`TestProxy`) receives a trap sent from Management Agent (MA, object of `TrapSenderVersion2`) the result of forward is true though the trap never arrives to the Network Management System (NMS, object of `TrapReceiver`).

**Could you please give me some good advice and preferably provide a sample of a proxy agent that works for you?**

---

TestProxy.java

```
public class TestProxy extends BaseAgent {    
    //MA - Management Agent which should report its trap to NMS
    public static final String ADDRESS_MA = "127.0.0.1/2163";//"172.19.0.1/161";
    //NMS - Network Management System which should receive trap from MA
    public static final String ADDRESS_NMS = "127.0.0.1/2162";//"10.30.34.17/162";

    // initialize Log4J logging
    static {
        LogFactory.setLogFactory(new Log4jLogFactory());
        ma = new UdpAddress(ADDRESS_MA);//"172.19.0.1/161");
        nms = new UdpAddress(ADDRESS_NMS);//"10.30.34.17/162");
    }

    static final UdpAddress ma;   // Managed Agent
    static final UdpAddress nms;  // Network Management System
    protected String address;

    /**
     * Creates the test agent with a file to read and store the boot counter and
     * a file to read and store its configuration.
     *
     * @param bootCounterFile a file containing the boot counter in serialized
     * form (as expected by BaseAgent).
     * @param configFile a configuration file with serialized management
     * information.
     * @throws IOException if the boot counter or config file cannot be read
     * properly.
     */
    public TestProxy(File bootCounterFile, File configFile) throws IOException {
        super(bootCounterFile, configFile, null);//new CommandProcessor(new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID())));
        setAgent(new CommandProcessor(new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID())) {
            @Override
            public void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent event) {
                processTrap(event);//   super.processPdu(event);
            }
        });
    }

    public void processTrap(CommandResponderEvent event) {
        System.out.println("!!! inside processTrap ");
        OctetString contextEngineID;
        OctetString contextName;
        if (event.getPDU() instanceof ScopedPDU) {
            ScopedPDU pdu = (ScopedPDU) event.getPDU();
            contextEngineID = pdu.getContextEngineID();
            contextName = pdu.getContextName();
        } else {
            contextEngineID = new OctetString(getInternalEngineID(event.getPeerAddress()));
            contextName = new OctetString();
        }
        System.out.println("secName: " + new String(event.getSecurityName()));
        PDU pdu = event.getPDU();
        System.out.println("Trap Type = " + pdu.getType());
        System.out.println("Variables = " + pdu.getVariableBindings());
        ProxyForwardRequest request = new ProxyForwardRequest(event, new CoexistenceInfo(null, contextEngineID, contextName));
        boolean forawrdResult = defaultProxyForwarder.forward(request);
        System.out.println("contextEngineID: " + contextEngineID + ";   contextName:" + contextName + ";   forawrdResult: " + forawrdResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws IOException {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerManagedObjects() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void addNotificationTargets(SnmpTargetMIB targetMIB,
            SnmpNotificationMIB notificationMIB) {
        targetMIB.addDefaultTDomains();
        TDomainAddressFactoryImpl factory = new TDomainAddressFactoryImpl();
        System.out.println("factory.getTransportDomain(nms)[0]: " + factory.getTransportDomain(nms)[0] + "   factory.getAddress(nms): " + factory.getAddress(nms));
        targetMIB.addTargetAddress(new OctetString("notification"),
                factory.getTransportDomain(nms)[0],
                factory.getAddress(nms),
                200, 1,
                new OctetString("notify"),
                new OctetString("v2c"),
                StorageType.permanent);
        targetMIB.addTargetParams(new OctetString("v2c"),
                MessageProcessingModel.MPv2c,
                SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPv2c,
                new OctetString("public"),
                SecurityLevel.NOAUTH_NOPRIV,
                StorageType.permanent);
        notificationMIB.addNotifyEntry(new OctetString("default"),
                new OctetString("notify"),
                SnmpNotificationMIB.SnmpNotifyTypeEnum.trap,
                StorageType.permanent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addViews(VacmMIB vacm) {
        vacm.addGroup(SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPv2c,
                new OctetString("cpublic"),
                new OctetString("v1v2group"),
                StorageType.nonVolatile);

        vacm.addAccess(new OctetString("v1v2group"), new OctetString("public"),
                SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_ANY,
                SecurityLevel.NOAUTH_NOPRIV,
                MutableVACM.VACM_MATCH_EXACT,
                new OctetString("fullReadView"),
                new OctetString("fullWriteView"),
                new OctetString("fullNotifyView"),
                StorageType.nonVolatile);

        vacm.addViewTreeFamily(new OctetString("fullReadView"), new OID("1.3"),
                new OctetString(), VacmMIB.vacmViewIncluded,
                StorageType.nonVolatile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addUsmUser(USM usm) {
    }

    /**
     * add Community-based agent for proxy-forwarding.
     *
     * @param communityName
     * @param address
     */
    public void addCommunityAgent(OctetString communityName, Address address) {
        TDomainAddressFactoryImpl factory = new TDomainAddressFactoryImpl();
        // add community-table
        OctetString snmpCommunityIndex = new OctetString("uniqueCommunityIndex");
        OctetString secName = new OctetString("uniqueSecName");
        OctetString snmpCommunityTransportTag = new OctetString("uniqueTransportTag");
        OctetString contextEngineID = new OctetString(getInternalEngineID(address));
        System.out.println(contextEngineID);

        Variable[] vars = new Variable[]{
            communityName, // community name
            secName, // security name
            contextEngineID, // context engine id
            new OctetString(), // context name
            snmpCommunityTransportTag, // transport tag
            new Integer32(StorageType.volatile_), // storage type
            new Integer32(RowStatus.active) // row status
        };
        MOTableRow row = getSnmpCommunityMIB().getSnmpCommunityEntry().createRow(
                snmpCommunityIndex.toSubIndex(true), vars);
        getSnmpCommunityMIB().getSnmpCommunityEntry().addRow(row);

        // add target-parameters-table
        OctetString snmpTargetParamsName = new OctetString("uniqueTargetParamsName");
        getSnmpTargetMIB().addTargetParams(
                snmpTargetParamsName,
                MessageProcessingModel.MPv2c, // MessageProcessingModel.MPv1,
                SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPv2c,// SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPv1,
                communityName,
                SecurityLevel.NOAUTH_NOPRIV,
                StorageType.volatile_);

        // add target-address-table
        OctetString snmpTargetAddrName = new OctetString("uniqueTargetAddrName");
        System.out.println("factory.getTransportDomain(address)[0]: " + factory.getTransportDomain(address)[0] + "   factory.getAddress(address): " + factory.getAddress(address));
        getSnmpTargetMIB().addTargetAddress(
                snmpTargetAddrName,
                factory.getTransportDomain(address)[0],
                factory.getAddress(address),
                1500,
                1,
                snmpCommunityTransportTag,
                snmpTargetParamsName,
                StorageType.volatile_);

        // add proxy-table(trap)
        OctetString snmpProxyName1 = new OctetString("uniqueProxyName1");
        getSnmpProxyMIB().addProxyEntry(
                snmpProxyName1,
                ProxyForwarder.PROXY_TYPE_NOTIFY,
                contextEngineID,
                new OctetString(),
                snmpTargetParamsName,
                null,
                new OctetString("nms"),
                StorageType.volatile_);

        // add proxy-table(get)
        OctetString snmpProxyName2 = new OctetString("uniqueProxyName2");
        getSnmpProxyMIB().addProxyEntry(
                snmpProxyName2,
                ProxyForwarder.PROXY_TYPE_READ,
                contextEngineID,
                new OctetString(),
                new OctetString("SHA"),
                snmpTargetAddrName,
                null,
                StorageType.volatile_);
    }

    byte[] getInternalEngineID(Address address) {
        // NOTE: generate EngineID without PortNumber for return-value (ID) be same
        //  at request/response and notify.
        OctetString id;
        if (address instanceof IpAddress) {
            id = new OctetString(((IpAddress) address).getInetAddress().getAddress());
        } else {
            id = new OctetString();
        }
        return MPv3.createLocalEngineID(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initTransportMappings() throws IOException {
        transportMappings = new TransportMapping[1];
        Address addr = GenericAddress.parse(address);
        System.out.println("address: " + address);
        TransportMapping tm = TransportMappings.getInstance().createTransportMapping(addr);
        transportMappings[0] = tm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void unregisterManagedObjects() {
        // here we should unregister those objects previously registered...
    }

    @Override
    protected void addCommunities(SnmpCommunityMIB communityMIB) {
        Variable[] com2sec = new Variable[]{
            new OctetString("public"), // community name
            new OctetString("cpublic"), // security name
            getAgent().getContextEngineID(), // local engine ID
            new OctetString("public"), // default context name
            new OctetString(), // transport tag
            new Integer32(StorageType.nonVolatile), // storage type
            new Integer32(RowStatus.active) // row status
        };
        MOTableRow row = communityMIB.getSnmpCommunityEntry().createRow(
                new OctetString("public2public").toSubIndex(true), com2sec);
        communityMIB.getSnmpCommunityEntry().addRow(row);
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerSnmpMIBs() {
        super.registerSnmpMIBs();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String address;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            address = args[0];
        } else {
            address = "0.0.0.0/2161";
        }
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        try {
            final TestProxy testProxyAgent = new TestProxy(new File(""), new File(""));//new File("SNMP4JTestAgentBC.cfg"), new File("SNMP4JTestAgentConfig.cfg"));
            testProxyAgent.address = address;
            testProxyAgent.init();
            testProxyAgent.loadConfig(ImportModes.UPDATE_CREATE);
            testProxyAgent.addShutdownHook();
            testProxyAgent.getServer().addContext(new OctetString("public"));
            testProxyAgent.finishInit();
            // NOTE: add SNMPv1-Trap (community-name: private) from Managed-Agent 'ma' as ProxyForward target.
            testProxyAgent.addCommunityAgent(new OctetString("private"), ma);
            testProxyAgent.run();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

TrapReceiver.java

```
public class TrapReceiver implements CommandResponder {    
    public synchronized void listen(TransportIpAddress address) throws IOException {
        AbstractTransportMapping transport;
        if (address instanceof TcpAddress) {
            transport = new DefaultTcpTransportMapping((TcpAddress) address);
        } else {
            transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping((UdpAddress) address);
        }
        ThreadPool threadPool = ThreadPool.create("DispatcherPool", 10);
        MessageDispatcher mDispathcher = new MultiThreadedMessageDispatcher(
                threadPool, new MessageDispatcherImpl());
        // add message processing models
        mDispathcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv1());
        mDispathcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c());
        // add all security protocols
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols();
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new Priv3DES());
        // Create Target
        CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
        target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));

        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(mDispathcher, transport);
        snmp.addCommandResponder(this);
        transport.listen();
        System.out.println("Listening on " + address);
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called whenever a pdu is received on the given port
     * specified in the listen() method
     *
     * @param cmdRespEvent
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent cmdRespEvent) {
        System.out.println("Received PDU...");
        PDU pdu = cmdRespEvent.getPDU();
        if (pdu != null) {
            System.out.println("Trap Type = " + pdu.getType());
            System.out.println("Variables = " + pdu.getVariableBindings());
            if (pdu.getType() == PDU.INFORM) {
                System.out.println("INFORM message received");
                pdu.setErrorIndex(0);
                pdu.setErrorStatus(0);
                pdu.setType(PDU.RESPONSE);
                StatusInformation statusInformation = new StatusInformation();
                StateReference ref = cmdRespEvent.getStateReference();
                try {
                    System.out.println(cmdRespEvent.getPDU());
                    cmdRespEvent.getMessageDispatcher().returnResponsePdu(
                            cmdRespEvent.getMessageProcessingModel(),
                            cmdRespEvent.getSecurityModel(),
                            cmdRespEvent.getSecurityName(),
                            cmdRespEvent.getSecurityLevel(),
                            pdu,
                            cmdRespEvent.getMaxSizeResponsePDU(),
                            ref,
                            statusInformation);
                } catch (MessageException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Error while sending response: " + ex.getMessage());
                    LogFactory.getLogger(TrapReceiver.class).error(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogFactory.setLogFactory(new Log4jLogFactory());
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        TrapReceiver snmp4jTrapReceiver = new TrapReceiver();
        try {
            snmp4jTrapReceiver.listen(new UdpAddress(TestProxy.ADDRESS_NMS));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogFactory.getLogger(TrapReceiver.class).error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

TrapSenderVersion2.java

```
public class TrapSenderVersion2 {
    public static final String community = "private";
    // Sending Trap for sysLocation of RFC1213
    public static final String Oid = "1.3.6.1.2.1.100.1.1";//".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8";
    //IP of Local Host
    public static final String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    //Ideally Port 162 should be used to send receive Trap, any other available Port can be used
    public static final int port = 2161;

    /**
     * This methods sends the V1 trap to the localhost on the given port
     */
    public void sendTrap_Version2() {
        try {
            // Create Transport Mapping
            TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping(new UdpAddress(TestProxy.ADDRESS_MA));
            transport.listen();
            // Create Target
            CommunityTarget cTarget = new CommunityTarget();
            cTarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
            cTarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
            cTarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
            cTarget.setRetries(2);
            cTarget.setTimeout(5000);
            // Create PDU for V2
            PDU pdu = new PDU();
            // need to specify the system up time
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new OctetString(new Date().toString())));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID(Oid)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress, new IpAddress(ipAddress)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(Oid), new OctetString("Major")));
            pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);
            // Send the PDU
            Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
            System.out.println("Sending V2 Trap... Check Wheather NMS is Listening or not? ");
            snmp.notify(pdu, cTarget);
            snmp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrapSenderVersion2 trapV2 = new TrapSenderVersion2();
        trapV2.sendTrap_Version2();
    }
}
```